# Esb incorrectly adding its context to the endpoint URL

Tags: wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

I'm currently developing a proxy service using ESB. The service first uses a callout mediator to call a service in DSS and after calls the final endpoint. The DSS endpoint is defined as a WSDL endpoint.

The proxy service URL is, e.g. `<host>/esb/services/exampleService`, and when I send a post to the service it tries to add this context to the URL of the DSS endpoint, giving out an exception in DSS, namely:

> `The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) <host>/services/dssservice.SOAP11Endpoint/esb/services/exampleService`

Is there a way to stop ESB from adding on to the URL?

Callout Configuration:

```
    <callout action="urn:exampleservice" endpointKey="DSSEndpoint"initAxis2ClientOptions="false">
        <source type="envelope"/>
        <target
          xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
          xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
          xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
      </callout>
```

If you require more information, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define this property before call mediator :

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```